# HTML form creation upon click

Tags: javascript, html

What is the correct syntax for creating a form when a div is clicked with javascript?  I've made a picture button, and I just want this form to appear in place of the button when clicked, but I can't get how it should look.  I only want to use some basic javascript and HTML if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to have the form already built in your html and then just use javascript or jquery to change the display style when the button is clicked.

Comment: I've tried this by setting its visibility to hidden, and then setting the innerHTML of the button to that of the form, which made it appear in the correct place, but I couldn't enter data there because it was hidden.

Comment: @Sam hmm is there any way you could post some of your code? it would make it a bit easier for me to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an `<a>` tag. But a div would work too.

**HTML**

```
<a class="myLink">Button</a>

<div class="form">
<form>
...
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form {display:none;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".myLink").live("click", function(){
        if(!$(".form").is(":visible"))
        {
            $(".form").show();
        }
    });
});
```